# How to add a custom button to Django admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-admin

I want to add a custom button right next to the SAVE button in my admin change form. I tried to add a button in submit_line.html

```
<input type="submit" action = "admin/{{id??}}" value="show PDF" name="show PDF{{ onclick_attrib }}/>
```

But, it doesn't redirect to my given page and I don't know how to pass the current id.
Actually, I dont think it's a good idea to change submit_line.html anyways, because I only want it in one model. Is there a better solution for that?

Comment: Have a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can add your own logic. Here you check app verbose name, to show that button only in your app:

```
{% if opts.verbose_name == 'Your app verbose name' %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Show PDF' %}" name="_show_pdf" {{ onclick_attrib }}/>{% endif %}
```

and in your admin.py:

```
class YourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        if '_continue' in request.POST:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(obj.get_admin_url())
        elif '_show_pdf' in request.POST:
            # Do some stuf here( show pdf in your case)
```

Comment: What happens when you update Djangos Version while using this approach?

Comment: @Jingo Not sure if in dev version were some changes in this place,but if logic will be changed in new version you will need to rewrite you app according to latest version. I think this could be related to a lot of code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom button **right next to "SAVE" button on "Add" form and "Change" form for a specifc admin**.

First, in **the root django project directory**, create **"templates/admin/custom_change_form.html"** and **"templates/admin/submit_line.html"** as shown below:

[image]

Next, copy & paste **all the code of "change_form.html" under django library** whose path is **"django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html"** to **"templates/admin/custom_change_form.html"** as shown below:

```html
# "templates/admin/custom_change_form.html"

{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls static admin_modify %}

{% block extrahead %}{{ block.super }}
<script src="{% url 'admin:jsi18n' %}"></script>
{{ media }}
{% endblock %}

... Much more code below
```

Next, copy & paste **all the code of "submit_line.html" under django library** whose path is **"django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/submit_line.html"** to **"templates/admin/submit_line.html"** as shown below:

```html
# "templates/admin/submit_line.html"

{% load i18n admin_urls %}
<div class="submit-row">
{% block submit-row %}
{% if show_save %}<input type="submit" value="{% translate 'Save' %}" class="default" name="_save">{% endif %}

... Much more code below
```

Next, add the code below between **"{% block submit-row %}"** and **"{% if show_save %}"** on **"templates/admin/submit_line.html"**. ***style="float:right;margin-left:8px;"** is important for this code below to put **a custom button right next to "SAVE" button**:

```html
{% if custom_button %}
<input type="submit" style="float:right;margin-left:8px;" value="{% translate 'Custom button' %}" name="_custom_button">
{% endif %}
```

So, this is the full code as shown below:

```html
# "templates/admin/submit_line.html"

{% load i18n admin_urls %}
<div class="submit-row">
{% block submit-row %}
{% if custom_button %}
<input type="submit" style="float:right;margin-left:8px;" value="{% translate 'Custom button' %}" name="_custom_button">
{% endif %}
{% if show_save %}<input type="submit" value="{% translate 'Save' %}" class="default" name="_save">{% endif %}

... Much more code below
```

Next, this is **the settings for templates** in **"settings.py"**:

```py
# "settings.py"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Then, add **"os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')"** to **"DIRS"** as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"

import os # Here

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], # Here
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Now, this is **"Person" model** as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Then, this is **"Person" admin** as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person) # Here
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

So next, for **"Person" admin**, set **"admin/custom_change_form.html"** to **"change_form_template"**, set **"True"** to **"extra_context['custom_button']"** in **"changeform_view()"** and set **"response_add()"** and **"response_change()"** to define the action after pressing **"Custom button"** on **"Add" form** and **"Change" form** respectively as shown below. *Whether or not setting **"response_add()"** and **"response_change()"**, inputted data to fields is saved after pressing **"Custom button"** on **"Add" form** and **"Change" form** respectively:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = "admin/custom_change_form.html" # Here
    
    def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        
        extra_context['custom_button'] = True # Here
        
        return super().changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None): # Here

        if "_custom_button" in request.POST:
            # Do something
            return super().response_add(request, obj, post_url_continue)
        else:
            # Do something
            return super().response_add(request, obj, post_url_continue)

    def response_change(self, request, obj): # Here
        
        if "_custom_button" in request.POST:
            # Do something
            return super().response_change(request, obj)
        else:
            # Do something
            return super().response_change(request, obj)
```

Finally, **"Custom button"** is added **at the bottom of "Add" form and "Change" form** for **"Person" admin** as shown below:

[image]

[image]

In addition, for **"Person" admin**, you can replace **"changeform_view()"** with **"render_change_form()"** set **"context.update({"custom_button": True})"** as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = "admin/custom_change_form.html"
    
    def render_change_form(self, request, context, add=False, change=False, form_url="", obj=None):        
        
        context.update({"custom_button": True}) # Here

        return super().render_change_form(request, context, add, change, form_url, obj)

    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):

        if "_custom_button" in request.POST:
            # Do something
            return super().response_add(request, obj, post_url_continue)
        else:
            # Do something
            return super().response_add(request, obj, post_url_continue)

    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        
        if "_custom_button" in request.POST:
            # Do something
            return super().response_change(request, obj)
        else:
            # Do something
            return super().response_change(request, obj)
```

Then, **"Custom button"** is added **at the bottom of "Add" form and "Change" form** for **"Person" admin** as well as shown below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Django1.10:

I would do it as follows, to avoid the verbosity and extra template processing of the accepted answer

1) Extend `admin/change_form.html` in your app's template directory (you are namespacing your app's templates, I hope) and override block `submit_row`:

```html
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block submit_row %}
    <div class="submit-row">
    {% if extra_buttons %}
        {% for button in extra_buttons %}
            {{ button }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if show_save %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save' %}" class="default" name="_save" />{% endif %}
    {% if show_delete_link %}
        {% url opts|admin_urlname:'delete' original.pk|admin_urlquote as delete_url %}
        <p class="deletelink-box"><a href="{% add_preserved_filters delete_url %}" class="deletelink">{% trans "Delete" %}</a></p>
    {% endif %}
    {% if show_save_as_new %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save as new' %}" name="_saveasnew" />{% endif %}
    {% if show_save_and_add_another %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and add another' %}" name="_addanother" />{% endif %}
    {% if show_save_and_continue %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and continue editing' %}" name="_continue" />{% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

This assumes, of course, that `button`'s string representation is an appropriate browser `input` or `button` element, and is marked safe with `django.utils.safestring.mark_safe`. Alternatively, you could use the `safe` template filter or access the attributes of `button` directly to construct the `<input>`. In my opinion, it's better to isolate such things to the python level.

2) Override `MyModelAdmin.change_view` and `MyModelAdmin.change_form_template`:

```python
change_form_template = "my_app/admin/change_form.html"

def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    extra_context = extra_context or self.extra_context()
    return super(PollAdmin, self).change_view(
        request, object_id, form_url, extra_context=extra_context,
    )
```

Comment: I think someone downvoted because your template suggestion is incorrect. E.g. on Django 1.10.6 **change_form.html** doesn't have `submit_row` block. But I upvoted your answer because you gave me a good idea where to put the code for my custom button - `change_view()` is a right place for that.

Comment: Ah; thanks @VladT. I'll look into it. Maybe I got my versions mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I only needed for users to do a custom action only after they saved, like "Add another", other buttons such as "export to pdf" I put in the change list as there it's super easy to add buttons.

If you are here for a case like mine the built-in messages framework will do the trick.

adding a response message is simple and you will need to override the
admin class `save_model`, goes like this:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    # if new model
    if not change:
        message_html = "<a href='http://yourSITE/admin/appname/appmodel/add/'>Add another</a>"
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, mark_safe(message_html))
    super(YourAdminClass, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

there are 4 different types of messages (I changed the css of INFO) and they are displayed in the screenshot

[image]