# How to save model data using custom button instead of using Save button in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to add a custom button X along with Save button in admin form and whenever I click the button X I want to save the current data and send an email.

I don't want to send email after every save so cannot use `post_save` signals. I am able to add the custom button. How can I add this functionality for button X in the detail page?

Comment: please add your scripts whatever you have done so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override **admin/change_form.html**, check how to [Overriding admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates)

In `admin/change_form.html`, you can find this line:

```
{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}{% submit_row %}{% endblock %}
```

`{% submit_row %}` is where the list of buttons are rendered out, you can start by extending the `change_form` to add a new button:

```
{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}

{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}
    {{ block.super }} <!-- or simply {% submit_row %} -->
     
    <div class="submit-row">
      <input type="submit" value="X" name="_button_x">
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

After you have added the new button, you can specify what template is going to be used for the change page.

> `response_change` is called after the admin form is submitted and just
> after the object and all the related instances have been saved. You
> can override it to change the default behavior after the object has
> been changed.

```
@admin.register(YourModel)
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # specify the new template you would like to use
    change_form_template = "<change_form_template>"

    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        if "_button_x" in request.POST:
            # customization here
            ...
        return super().response_change(request, obj)
```

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978362/create-custom-buttons-in-admin-change-form-in-django/30755936)

Comment: It worked. Thank you !

Comment: @SushmaYadav you are welcome :),  though it's closed