# How do I change the text/value of "Add [Model-Name]" button in Django Admin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, django-admin-tools

When we login to Django Admin Interface as a superuser, we see the list of models on the left sidebar. When we click on any model name, we go to the list display page of that model which have 'Add [Model-Name]" button on uuper right corner. How do I change the text/value of that button? In my case, I have `User` Model, and I want to change the "Add User" text on list display page of `User` Model to "Invite User". How do I accomplish that? I have encircled the button with red in the screenshot attached.

[Django Admin Interface Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fU5V3.png)

I have tried different solutions told in this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978362/create-custom-buttons-in-admin-change-form-in-django) question and in this [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates). But I am unable to achieve. I tried to override `change_form.html` by changing `{% blocktranslate with name=opts.verbose_name %}Add {{ name }}{% endblocktranslate %}` to `{% blocktranslate with name=opts.verbose_name %}Invite {{ name }}{% endblocktranslate %}`. I put the overriden file `change_form.html` in `pricingmeister/accounts/templates/admin/`. But i could not see the change.

The hierarchy of my Django Project and folders is below:

[Django Project Hierarchy Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Chp6I.png)

Below is my `settings.py` (truncated some code to show only relevant part of code

```
.
.
.
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Local Apps
    "pricingmeister.accounts",
    "pricingmeister.core",
    # Django Apps
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
]
.
.
.
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]
.
.
.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Meta class options {verbose_name, verbose_name_plural} to change model name.

for example,

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    ...
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Invite User"
        verbose_name_plural = "Invite Users"
```

for more details please  [read django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/options/#verbose-name)